# Prove $V_{e} + V_{o} = V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Prove $V_{e} + V_{o} = V$ where $V_{e}$ is a subset of even functions from $R$ into $R$, $V_{o}$ is a subset of odd functions from $R$ into $R$. I have proved $V_{e}$, $V_{o}$ are subspaces and $\forall$ $f\in V,$ $ f(x) ={f(x) + f(-x) \over 2} + {f(x) - f(-x) \over 2}$ thus every f is a sum of an odd and an even function.
Does this prove $V \subseteq V_{e} + V_{o}$ or $V_{e} + V_{o} = V$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $V$ is the set of *all* functions $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.

Strictly speaking, 
$$
f(x) ={f(x) + f(-x) \over 2} + {f(x) - f(-x) \over 2}
$$
proves $V \subseteq V_{e} + V_{o}$.

But since  $V_{e} + V_{o} \subseteq V$, we have $V_{e} + V_{o} = V$.